# Sometimes Camera.open returns null or sometimes it's working fine

Tags: android

I am trying to get camera instance in on-create method using `Camera.open()` for showing camera preview.But sometimes it returns null.How can i handle this problem.

I have given  permission in `manifest` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Watching logcat should help.  It should only be returning null if it can't open the camera because another activity is actively using it and hasn't released it.

By that same token, you should be releasing the camera in your onPause method.

Comment: How Can I release camera in on-pause whether it had not open in on-create.Actually   I am unable to open Camera in on create of activity.I think camera hardware is locked by another app .Is it possible to unlock (release) first.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your application and try catching that moment when this method returns null, this might give you some updates.

Also specify `"android:required="true"` for your `uses-feature` tag, this will ensure that the app will run only if the camera is available.

As documentation states `open()` returns null only if the camera is not available, so this will check if it's not a hardware problem.

> If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null. ([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29))

Comment: Camera is available but I am unable to open Camera in on create of activity.I think camera hardware is locked by another app .Is it possible to unlock (release) first.